# AngularJs ng-if directive not working?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very new to AngularJs so I'm unsure of the `ngif` syntax. I have a table and I need to change the class of the `<td>` depending on the value of `component.status`. 
Everything works except for the `ngif` directive

My Array:

```
$scope.components = 
    [
    {type: "Dispacther",        component: "Dispatcher2",  created: "2016-05-20T01:44:56.113", status: "Live"},
    {type: "Mobilizer",         component: "Mobility3",    created: "2016-05-25T07:34:30.019", status: "Down"},
    {type: "Listener",          component: "ADT 22146",    created: "2016-05-20T01:44:56.113", status: "Live"},
    {type: "OutBound Charge",   component: "Billing 92",   created: "2016-05-20T01:44:56.113", status: "Live"},
    {type: "Listener",          component: "22064",        created: "2016-05-20T01:44:56.113", status: "Live"},
    {type: "Dispacther",        component: "Dispacther1",  created: "2016-05-21T00:48:50.433", status: "Warning"}
];
```

My attempt so far:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="component in components">
  <td >{{component.type}}</td>
  <td>{{component.component}}</td>
  <td>{{component.created}}</td>
  <td ng-if="component.status == Live" class="alert-success">{{component.status}}</td>
  <td ng-if="component.status == Warning" class="alert-warning">{{component.status}}</td>
  <td ng-if="component.status == Down" class="alert-danger">{{component.status}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: why not use ng-class directive check the docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: If I remember correctly, you want to wrap `Live` etc in single quotes, unless they are scope variables

Comment: @SterlingArcher This worked perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: To expand on @AyoubOlk comment, here is a working example of ng-class: https://jsfiddle.net/qbe07cy4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work, however you need to encapsulate the status value with quotes '' ( ng-if="component.status == 'Live'" )

```
  <tr ng-repeat="component in components">
  <td >{{component.type}}</td>
  <td>{{component.component}}</td>
  <td>{{component.created}}</td>
  <td ng-if="component.status == 'Live'" class="alert-success">{{component.status}}</td>
  <td ng-if="component.status == 'Warning'" class="alert-warning">{{component.status}}</td>
  <td ng-if="component.status == 'Down'" class="alert-danger">{{component.status}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Live` is a string not variable and to compare two elements, please use `===` (compare `value` and compare `type`) instead of `==` (just compare `value`).
Change:

```
<td ng-if="component.status == Live" class="alert-success">{{component.status}}</td>
```

To:

```
<td ng-if="component.status === 'Live'" class="alert-success">{{component.status}}</td>
```

But in your case, I think you should use `ng-class`.
Change:

```
<td ng-if="component.status == Live" class="alert-success">{{component.status}}</td>
<td ng-if="component.status == Warning" class="alert-warning">{{component.status}}</td>
<td ng-if="component.status == Down" class="alert-danger">{{component.status}}</td>
```

To:

```
<td ng-class="{'alert-success': component.status === 'Live', 'alert-warning':  component.status === 'Warning', 'alert-danger': component.status === 'Down'}">{{component.status}}</td>
```

Inside `ng-class`: `{'alert-success': component.status === 'Live', 'alert-warning':  component.status === 'Warning', 'alert-danger': component.status === 'Down'}`